# Creating .csv file with PHP

Tags: php, csv, opencart

I'm trying to create a .csv file with the following code:

```
public function export_modis_categories_xml(){  
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="category_export.csv"');    
$category_rs = $this->db->query('
  SELECT        
    '.DB_PREFIX.'category.category_id, 
    '.DB_PREFIX.'category.parent_id, 
    '.DB_PREFIX.'category_description.name, 
    '.DB_PREFIX.'category_description.description 
  FROM          
    '.DB_PREFIX.'category
  INNER JOIN    
    '.DB_PREFIX.'category_description
  ON    
    '.DB_PREFIX.'category.category_id = '.DB_PREFIX.'category_description.category_id
');
error_log($category_rs);
$category_rs = $category_rs->rows;
$category_export_array = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($category_rs as $cat){
  $category_id  = ($category_rs[$i]['category_id']  =! '' ? $category_rs[$i]['category_id'] : '');
  $parent_id    = ($category_rs[$i]['parent_id']    =! '' ? $category_rs[$i]['parent_id']   : '');
  $name         = ($category_rs[$i]['name']         =! '' ? $category_rs[$i]['name']        : '');
  $description  = ($category_rs[$i]['description']  =! '' ? $category_rs[$i]['description'] : '');

  $category_export_array[$i] = $category_id.';'.$parent_id.';'.$name.';'.$description;      
  $i++;  
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$header_array = array('headers'=>'categorie_id;parent_id;name;description');
fputcsv($fp, $header_array);
fputcsv($fp, $category_export_array);
fclose($fp);  
}
```

This worked on one site, as it is a OpenCart plugin, but not on another site.

The weird thing is, I don't get any error. Not in the error log or in web view. It doesn't give me file, and the site doesn't go blank...

Comment: Aside from the invalid Content-Type heading, describe what you mean by "doesn't work". Does it generate a file with the wrong data? Does it generate a Word file rather than an Excel file? Does it empty your fridge? Does it download an empty file? Does it give a blank screen in your browser?

Comment: If it is on different server than the working site make sure You have permission to write to *stdout* (php://output).

Comment: It does nothing, and that is what i hate about it.. I wish i got an error or something, but the windows just stays the same

Comment: It is on the same server. I've copied it from our developer domain to a live server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error, it was never in my code..

The form that calls the function wasn't sending the right POST name, so the function wasn't triggerd.

Sorry for bothering everyone with my stupidity..